# Redirection Based on Referring Domain

Tags: javascript, redirect, referrer

I'm trying to protect a page from unauthorized access, and would like to prevent everyone **not coming from my domain** to be redirected.

I know this has been asked on SO before but I've implemented those code variations and they haven't worked for me.

Here's the Javascript I have tried so far:

```
if (document.referrer != "http://example.net") 
location.href = "http://example.org";
```

I am trying to make it so anyone not coming from `example.net` will be redirected to `example.org`.

Anyone have some advice as to how to get this working properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a heads up, anybody coming here with JS turned off can easily circumvent this.

Comment: it's a logic which have to be in your control, eg. in the server

Comment: So, should I be looking into a php vershion of this javascript?

Comment: You should test for "starts with" instead of "equals".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!/mydomain\.com/i.test(document.referrer)) {
    location.href = "http://goaway.org";
}
</script>
```

Please note that is trivial to fake the referrer.

Comment: Hmm, this one suffers from the same problem as the other scripts I've tested. 

For some reason it is not pickup up my referrer and just goes straight to my backup site.

Could it be the fact that I'm accessing it via a mobile device that this doesn't work as intended?